# jqGrid and jqPivot: Keeping spaces in pivoted column names?

Tags: jqgrid, jqpivot

I'm using jqGrid with the [jqPivot API](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:pivotsettings).

The problem I'm encountering is that jqPivot removes the spaces from the pivoted column names.  Is there any way to change this behaviour?

eg.

```
var mydata = [
    {id: "1", emp:"Michelle", product:"A A", sold:"8"},
    {id: "2", emp:"Tania", product:"A A", sold:"3"},
    {id: "6", emp:"Mark", product:"A B", sold:"1"},
    {id: "3", emp:"Tommy", product:"A B", sold:"5"},
    {id: "4", emp:"Dave", product:"B B", sold:"2"},
    {id: "5", emp:"Carol", product:"B B", sold:"5"},
];

var grid = $("#grid");

grid.jqGrid('jqPivot',
    mydata, {
        xDimension: [{
            dataName: 'id',
            label: 'ID',
            width: 90
        }, {
            dataName: 'emp',
            label: 'Employee',
            width: 90
        }, ],
        yDimension: [{
            dataName: 'product'
        }],
        aggregates: [{
            member: 'sold',
            aggregator: 'sum',
            width: 50,
            label: 'Sold'
        }, ],
        colTotals: true

    }, {
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        pager: "#pager",
        caption: "Daily Sales"
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aUDHx/968/

Instead of "A A" and "A B" etc. it displays the columns as "AA" and "AB".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that it's a problem. The reason is [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.pivot.js#L180) of jqPivot code. As a quick and dirty workaround I could suggest you to use [converter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:pivotsettings#ydimension) which replace the space to some other character like `_`, `&ensp;` (`&#x2002;`) or `&nbsp;`.

```js
yDimension: [{
    dataName: 'product',
    converter: function (val) {return val.replace(/\s/g, '&#x2002;');}
}],
```

See the modified demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/aUDHx/970/.

Comment: Thanks, I tried using a converter but I wasn't quite sure of how to code it.  Your solution works perfectly.